# Quantum vacuum fluctuations in BEC

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, vacuum, bose-einstein-condensate

I'm trying to understand Jeff Steinhauer's experiment and for some steps I don't see how it works physically. 
But generally, why the quantum vacuum fluctuations are *guaranteed* by the underlying pointlike atoms composing a BEC?

And if vacuum fluctuations generate excitations (i.e phonon) what is the link with the propagation of wave? Does this excitation produce waves?
There are propagating waves plus excitation due to vacuum fluctuations?

And more specifically, he used the correlation between annihilation operators for demonstrated the Hawking radiation but why not the creation operators?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know anything about this specific experiment, but to answer "why the quantum vacuum fluctuations are guaranteed ... ", a point-like particle cannot sit still, due to Heisenberg uncertainty, and thus fluctuates.

Comment: so we can think about quantum fluctuation in Bose-Einstein condensate as what happens in vacuum, just it created pair of excitation (phonon) instead of pair of photon?

Comment: Phonons are collective modes in a system where individual particles are assumed to be connected by a sort of 'spring'. Thus, if a few particles jiggle, they will jiggle the rest too. You can show that such excitations/waves are bosonic in nature. Also, the energy spectrum of these phonons is continuous to 0. This means that no matter how small the fluctuation, there is a phonon with the corresponding energy. So yes, the zero-point motion of individual particles should induce phonons in the BEC.